# call back after all generated img in ng-repeat is loaded and rendered

Tags: jquery, angularjs, image

I have:

```
<div class ='container'>
  <div class  ='subcontainer'>
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items">
      <img class="grid-img" data-ng-src="<?php echo base_url();?>
      {{item.image_path}}menu.png"/> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want a call back function to notify when all the images in the subcontainer class is completely loaded and rendered. I have tried too many plugins but they dont fit with angularjs tag. I also tried a custom directive to load each image...some images are loaded but render is too slow. Somebody please help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search shows an interesting directive you can use called [onFinishRender](http://www.jomendez.com/2015/02/05/ng-repeat-onfinishrender-directive-angularjs/):

```
.directive('onFinishRender',['$timeout', '$parse', function ($timeout, $parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
      if (scope.$last === true) {
        $timeout(function () {
          scope.$emit('ngRepeatFinished');
          if(!!attr.onFinishRender){
            $parse(attr.onFinishRender)(scope);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
}])
```

His site shows how to set it up, try it and see if that works for you.